# How to convert Mongodb collection results into Array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to send my MongoDB collection results to a service -( Algolia to be precise)  as an array.

The results MongoDB return are not array in format. So am thinking if there is a way to convert the collection result into an array.

This is what it returns:

```
{ _id: 5b30c318ca1ea60cb8a55d2f,
  memeid: 'Z3Q7NC',
  url: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/memeafrica/image/upload/v1529922328/test/adam-levine_nxqpnt.gif',
  tags: 'laugh,laughing,laughing uncontrollaby ',
  caption: '',
  imgs: 'adam-levine.gif',
  __v: 0,
  uploadDate: 2018-06-25T10:25:28.940Z,
  tagarray: [ 'laugh', 'laughing', 'laughinguncontrollaby' ],
  views: 500 }
{ _id: 5b30c759ca1ea60cb8a55d30,
  memeid: '2oIjDP',
  url: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/memeafrica/image/upload/v1529923417/test/Debffc4XkAAuvLj_mvzvpz.jpg'
  tags: 'zuma',
  caption: '',
  imgs: 'Debffc4XkAAuvLj.jpg',
  __v: 0,
  uploadDate: 2018-06-25T10:43:37.859Z,
  tagarray: [ 'zuma' ],
  views: 2000 }
{ _id: 5b30d4b22904771be030db62,
  memeid: 'eLT1F',
  url: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/memeafrica/image/upload/v1529926834/test/crying_b6fjaf.gif',
  tags: 'laugh',
  caption: '',
  imgs: 'crying.gif',
  __v: 0,
  uploadDate: 2018-06-25T11:40:34.649Z,
  tagarray: [ 'laugh' ],
  views: 0 }
```

What am expecting:

```
[
{ _id: 5b30c318ca1ea60cb8a55d2f,
  memeid: 'Z3Q7NC',
  url: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/memeafrica/image/upload/v1529922328/test/adam-levine_nxqpnt.gif',
  tags: 'laugh,laughing,laughing uncontrollaby ',
  caption: '',
  imgs: 'adam-levine.gif',
  __v: 0,
  uploadDate: 2018-06-25T10:25:28.940Z,
  tagarray: [ 'laugh', 'laughing', 'laughinguncontrollaby' ],
  views: 500 }
{ _id: 5b30c759ca1ea60cb8a55d30,
  memeid: '2oIjDP',
  url: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/memeafrica/image/upload/v1529923417/test/Debffc4XkAAuvLj_mvzvpz.jpg'
  tags: 'zuma',
  caption: '',
  imgs: 'Debffc4XkAAuvLj.jpg',
  __v: 0,
  uploadDate: 2018-06-25T10:43:37.859Z,
  tagarray: [ 'zuma' ],
  views: 2000 }
{ _id: 5b30d4b22904771be030db62,
  memeid: 'eLT1F',
  url: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/memeafrica/image/upload/v1529926834/test/crying_b6fjaf.gif',
  tags: 'laugh',
  caption: '',
  imgs: 'crying.gif',
  __v: 0,
  uploadDate: 2018-06-25T11:40:34.649Z,
  tagarray: [ 'laugh' ],
  views: 0 }
]
```

My code:

```
meme.find({}, (err, meme) => {
  meme.forEach((meme) => {
    console.log(meme); 
  });
});
```

How do I manipulate the process so it can be array?

Thanks!

Comment: You're using Mongoose, so the `meme` in your `meme.find` callback _is_ an array; you're iterating over it and console logging each element individually. Maybe I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: Exactly. How do I turn it into Array?

Comment: `meme` already is an array.

Answer (score 4):

[The cursor object returned by `find()` has a `toArray()` method.](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#toarray)

```
meme.find().toArray((err, memes) => {
    console.log("retrieved memes:");
    console.log(memes);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use map. It'll iterate through each meme and add them to an array.

```
meme.find({}, (err, meme) => {
  const memes = meme.map(m => m);
  // Use the array, pass it to a service, or pass to a callback
});
```

Comment: When I run the code it is still returning object. `meme.find({}, (err, meme) => {
  const memes = meme.map(m => m);
  console.log(typeof memes); 
  // Use the array, pass it to a service, or pass to a callback
});`

Comment: The commented part   `// Use the array, pass it to a service, or pass to a callback` How do I pass to a callback? @jakeMiller